# Angular Strap $alert giving an error of not a function - no idea why

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-strap

I'm trying to use the Angular-Strap plugin to create messages for the user, as per this:

http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/#/alerts#alerts

and the following plunker

http://plnkr.co/edit/2xx07drMLCqmbmyVlv5n?p=preview

I'm sure i've added the module.config correctly as that's all ok, but in my controller, when I inject the $alert variable into my function I'm getting an error. Here is the error:

```
TypeError: object is not a function
    at AlertFactory (http://localhost:3000/components/angular-strap/dist/angular-strap.js:412:18)
    at new <anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/controllers/form-controller.js:92:17)
```

When I console.log($alert) - i get:

```
function AlertFactory(config) {

        var $alert = {};

        // Common vars
        var options = angular.extend({}, defaults, config);

        $alert = $modal(options);

        // Support scope as string options [/*title, content, */ type, dismissable]
        $alert.$scope.dismissable = !!options.dismissable;
        if(options.type) {
          $alert.$scope.type = options.type;
        }

        // Support auto-close duration
        var show = $alert.show;
        if(options.duration) {
          $alert.show = function() {
            show();
            $timeout(function() {
              $alert.hide();
            }, options.duration * 1000);
          };
        }

        return $alert;

      }
```

and here is how I'm injecting it:

```
angular.module('MyApp')
.controller('formController', ['$scope', 'Appointment', '$alert',  function($scope, Appointment, $alert) {
console.log($alert);

}]);
```

FYI - components/angular-strap/dist/angular-strap.js:412:18 ==  $alert = $modal(options), which makes me think that $module isn't loaded, but that should load with the rest of Angular Strap no?

Can someone help?

Comment: Hmm, maybe it's just me but I don't seem to see the error?(aside from the missing opening <div> tag on the html)
The custom alert pops out just fine.

Comment: yes - i think this issue is related to the UI-router states - I'm using nested states and I think that's causing the problem, but not sure how